# A good database system for lightweight schema-flexible problem

Tags: database, nosql

I'm looking for a DB system to use for a small project. My ideal DB would have the following features/requirements:

- **flexible schemas**: I have tuples that might have missing attributes, and others that might have special attributes not shared by the entire database
- **convenient front-end**: This DB would be part of a (most likely web-based) front-end where a non-tech-savvy user would enter data, ask queries and so on. So appropriate plugins with php would be handy.
- **query expressivity**: I have a reverse-scale problem - the database will never get terribly large (think of something like 50 new tuples each year) so I don't need something very fancy. I just want a system that admits fairly sophisticated querying (which is why a spreadsheet won't do)

I've looked into the usual NoSQL systems like MongoDB and CouchDB, and while they definitely could work, they seem like overkill for my relatively small problem. I was wondering if there was something much simpler that I could use.

Comment: SQL has been used to solve problems that fit your definition of "flexible schemas" for a long time, especially at your scale. What makes you think you need another technology? Is it because the non-tech-savvy user will need to change the schema often, and thus you need the change to be handled implicitly?

Comment: The schema will definitely change frequently, and most records will be missing many entries. If I just set up a regular mysql table, I'd have to run ALTER TABLE commands fairly often as the schema changes, wouldn't I  ?

Comment: You don't have to alter any table if you partition the entries into "common" and "rare", and then store the former in a matrix-form table and the latter in a list-form table. But to perform queries, you will need to pivot the entries from the list (but you can automate the pivoting). However, other than the ability to use SQL for queries (and thus the associated benefits like mature SQL tool support), it is not clear to me what other benefits you would enjoy by using such a method. So if non-SQL querying is fine with you, then indeed the newer systems you named are very fine.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the 'common' and 'rare' distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of SQLite. SQLite supports many of the basic features of DBMS's like MySQL such as querying with standard SQL, but runs as a single dll included into most programs. The database itself is stored as a single file, and with the amount of data you appear to want to put in it would probably be pretty insignificant in size. SQLite does work with PHP, and you can find a tutorial for getting started with it [Here.](http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitephptutorial/) Enjoy!

Comment: it didn't occur to me to check out SQLite. Thanks for the idea. I'll look into that as well. My worry is the potential lack of schema flexibility, but I'll dig into that.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it appears a doc store or a column store would work well for you.  As most nosql variants are for "big data", most of the nosql options will probably be overkill for what you're wanting to do.

How big is your dataset now?  If it's fairly small (matter of tens of gigs), then you would probably best served by an in-memory database.  That'll help with query execution, and you'd only need one node/server.

That said, something like mysql may be ok.  Since you mentioned just small amounts of data, that's what's drawing me to simplicity.

You can then use open-source tools such as Pentaho or Jaspersoft to extract out the data via reports.  They're very easy to setup and use.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: the db is miniscule. we're talking MB, not even GB. what are good in-memory db systems ?

Comment: Mysql does have a memory engine for tables.  The only problem is that you lose it when you kill the system.  You can also just load the data into an innodb table and then just load the data into memory when you start it up.  Long story short, with just Megabytes, unless you're counting the hundredths of milliseconds, then you're probably ok with just about any database.